# How to set x509certificate in a WCF client?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a property of type X509Certificate and I need to use this property to set the certificate in my WCF client. But the DefaultCertificate property seems to be of type X509Certificate2. Can anyone please suggest how to handle this? Thanks!

```
    public X509Certificate Certificate { get; set; }

    channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = this.Certificate;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [new X509Certificate2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223098.aspx) from your certificate:

```
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(this.Certificate);
```